# Usage of bisher and zuvor

Tags: difference

What is the difference between *zuvor* and *bisher*? Both mean before, but in what context are they used? Are they interchangeable?

> Sein Deutsch ist viel besser als bisher.
>
> Sein Deutsch ist viel besser als zuvor.

Comment: @wogsland: Kannst du bitte damit aufhören Uralt-Beiträge aus der Gruft zu holen? Jeder Beitrag aus den Jahren 2013 und 2014, den du editierst, rutscht durch das Editieren wieder an die Spitze der topaktuellen Fragen. Dort haben aber längst beantwortete und damit abgeschlossene Fragen nichts zu suchen. Wenn es einen aktuellen Grund gibt, eine bestimmte Frage zu editieren, dann ja. Aber bitte nicht, weil du dir krampfhaft einen Edit-Badge verdienen willst.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Auf [Meta](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/1210) hat es keine Stimmen dagegen gegeben, daher ist an Wogslands Vorgehen nichts auszusetzen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Bisher* means *up to this point* with *this point* being the *now* of the utterance. So *bisher* is synonymous to *bis jetzt* although the latter implies a change more strongly in my opinion.

> Bisher hab' ich Nudeln immer ohne Salz gekocht.(Now I changed my habbit, or I am asked to change it)

*zuvor* means *before that point* with *that point* being a random point in time that has been established in speech before.

> Ich tue die Nudeln ins Wasser, an das ich zuvor schon Salz getan hatte.

If *zuvor* just order two activities, it is synonymous with *vorher* and *davor*. But since it can also talk about habbits or things of duration, it is the only choice sometimes ... okay... except for *bis dahin*. which can express that too.

Comment: Und ich tue eine Tute kaufen und tue solange tuten, bis die Tute nicht mehr tuten tut. :)